# uppercase label in xcode storyboard not wanted

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I'm using xcode 6 with storyboard for ios app development.

I have a problem with UILabel in view controllers in storyboard: the text is simple and inlower case, but when I run the app in the simulator or in the device I see the Label text in UPPERCASE.

Labels have no outlets, and cannot be modified programmatically.
some one has a solution? I'd prefer not using IBOutlet and setting text by code..

Comment: There is either something unique about the way you make your labels, or you need to quit and restart Xcode.

Comment: the issue is not depending by my labels because appears sometimes and other times work fine... it's a bug of xcode, solved by restarting?

Comment: I don't know if it is a bug in Xcode. I have never seen it before. Try restarting Xcode and see what happens.

Answer (score 17):

I had somewhat similar problem. In my case everything(title, lables, button texts, etc.) was in upper case. I found out that "Localization Debugging" was on, so when I had language on iphone which was not supported by localization, it turned words automatically to upper case. When I disabled it, everything worked fine again.

Just go to "Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme" and there select "Run" and disable "Localization Debugging". (Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post images, otherwise I would put here screen)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself fot other people. 
Nothing to do with this strange thing. It seems a xcode bug. Sometimes the labels appears uppercased, other times are ok.
I discover a trick that was using the attributed text in storyboard. in this way it works correctly.
Another way is to use a outlet and setting the uilabel.text by code.
Bye