# iOS 11 lower case text shows as upper case in simulator

Tags: uitextfield, uilabel

I enter lower case text in my labels and text fields in my storyboard but they show as all caps when I run my app in the simulator. How can I fix this? I am specifying system font.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this link:
[uppercase label in xcode storyboard not wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332613/uppercase-label-in-xcode-storyboard-not-wanted)
Turning off localization debugging ("Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme" and there select "Run" and disable "Localization Debugging") solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check followings steps

1. In your class file check is you are updating text to uppercase
2. Is any localization string was updating for label or textfield